# Несколько таблиц с общим хедером

Tags: html, css

Имеется следующий макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Представляет из себя таблицу, разделенную на несолько подтаблиц, причем шапка таблицы общая для всех подтаблиц.

В чем заключается сложность.

Данные могут быть реактивные. Ширина колонок может меняться. При этом нужно, чтобы соответствующая ширина выставлялась для всех колонок во всех таблицах и для заголовков колонок в шапке одинаково.

Кроме того, таблица должна быть резиновой (с оговоркой о возможности горизонтального скролла при необходимости), а ширина колонок должна быть легко настраиваема без hardcoded-значений. Например, как это делается в CSS-гридах: `minmax(min-content, 1fr)`.

Не прошу готовую реализацию, интересуют **идеи** того, как лучше это все дело реализовать. Какие технологии использовать.

Использовать JavaScript для модификации CSS разрешается в крайнем случае, но не приветствуется (особенно, если это совсем уж костыли).

Может кто сталкивался с чем-то подобным, хотелось бы услышать разные варианты, ибо я пока в тупике.

Ах, да, чуть не забыл. Что я думаю по этому поводу.

Первая мысль - гриды и использовать. Точнее, использовать один общий грид контейнер, дочерним элементам по необходимости ставить `display: contents`. Однако проблема очевидна - хедеры в подтаблицах. Насколько я знаю, `display: contents` не даст нормально зарендерить эти шапки. Кроме того, довольно специфический отступы. Между подтаблицами отступы одни, в строках другие, я пока слабо представляю как (и можно ли вообще) это сделать.

Другой вариант (пока остановился на нем) - сначала все зарендерить, а потом JS'ом найти самую широкую колонку среди всех таблиц и сделать эту колонку одинаковой для всех таблиц и для общего хедера. Но, во-первых, это уже костыли, во-вторых, я даже боюсь себе представить, что может пойти не так. Плюс, реактивные данные. Будет довольно дорого пересчитывать таким образом ширину(ы) каждый раз при изменении данных.

В общем, прошу поделиться, кто что думаю на этот счет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать всё это в рамках одной таблицы. Со стилизацией, конечно, придётся повозиться (в том числе как-нибудь решить вопрос растягивания дивов по высоте ячеек при разном объеме контента), но вот примерный вариант я Вам набросал на скорую руку:

```css
body {
  background-color: #F8FAFB;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}
th, td {
  border: 0;
}
th > div,
td > div {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #E8ECEF;
  margin: -1px;
}
th > div.first {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
th > div.last {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
th > div:not(.last),
td > div:not(.last) {
  border-right: none;
}
td > div.first {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
td > div.last {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.inner-colspan {
  background-color: #F8FAFB;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  margin: 15px 10px -1px;
  border-left: 1px solid #E8ECEF;
  border-top: 1px solid #E8ECEF;
  border-right: 1px solid #E8ECEF !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><div class="first">number</div></th>
    <th><div>prop name</div></th>
    <th><div>bull name</div></th>
    <th><div>unit name</div></th>
    <th><div class="last">unit type</div></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
      <div class="inner-colspan">\/ 101 & 102</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="first"></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div class="last"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="first"></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div class="last"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="first"></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div class="last"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="first"></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div class="last"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
      <div class="inner-colspan">\/ 103</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="first"></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div class="last"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="first"></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div class="last"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
      <div class="inner-colspan">\/ 104</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="first"></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div class="last"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="first"></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div></div></td>
    <td><div class="last"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Проблема возникает с пунктом про простоту задания ширины колонкам. Представьте, что в первой колонке во всех таблицах будет двузначное число. И тогда мне нужно, чтобы колонка занимала ровно столько ширины, сколько занимает самое длинное из этих двухзначных чисел и ни пикселем больше, а остальные колонки при этом должны делить поровну все оставшееся расстояние между собой. Насколько я знаю, сделать такое без хаков вроде `width: 1%` невозможно. А так да, вариант с нативными таблицами - первое, что рассмотрел. В любом случае, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Или, еще нагляднее, если данные реактивные. Было 10 символов, стало 20, а ширина колонки при этом должна подстраиваться под самое длинное значение в ней.